# like a comment in a post throw an exception

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have a problem when I try using facebook php api to like a comment

To "Like" [this comment](http://www.facebook.com/MultiApps/posts/414687428597397?comment_id=3722461&offset=0&total_comments=1) I used

```
try {
    $temp = $facebook->api('/3722461/likes?access_token="' . $facebook->getAccessToken() . '"', 'POST');
    echo "ok";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

but this throws an exception

```
["error"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(36) "(#100) The parameter url is required"
      ["type"]=>
      string(14) "OAuthException"
      ["code"]=>
      int(100)
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you use a relative URL in the facebook api? Have you tried using a  full URL $facebook->api('http://somesite.com/3722461/likes?access_token...

Comment: I am using $temp = $facebook->api('http://www.facebook.com/416074/likes?access_token="' . $facebook->getAccessToken() . '"', 'POST');

Comment: but like of that comment doesn't increase, :(

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in my answer. Liking a comment should be possible via API, according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/#likes But you have to give the comment ID as `postID_commentID`, 414687428597397_3722461 in your specific case here.

Answer (score 0):

Some posts (such as Events) are not eligiable for having Likes (i.e. you can attend to it but cannot likes it) - in these cases you'll get this error